# Enabling/disabling buttons onclick through kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote a simple code to create a timer, and for this I added two buttons: Start and Stop. The idea is that when one of the buttons is enabled the other isn't, and viceversa.

The code below works, but I want to get the same behaviour using the kv file.

```
def update_time(self, instance):    
    timer = Clock.schedule_interval(self.timer, 1.0 / 1.0)
    instance.disabled = True
    self.stop_button.disabled = False

def stop_updating(self, instance):
    Clock.unschedule(self.timer)
    instance.disabled = True
    self.timer_button.disabled = False
```

If I try to use the code snippet below, the script throws an error because it is lacking one argument (instance).

```
Button:
    text: 'Start'
    on_press: root.update_time()
```

I know the "disabled" property in kv file exists, but I don't know how (or whether) to use it to modify the two buttons I want to be modified, onclick.

Any idea how to go about it?

**All script code**

```
class LandingScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def go_to_timer(self):
        clock_app.screen_manager.current = 'Timer'


class TimerScreen(GridLayout):
    current_time = StringProperty()
    timer_start = ObjectProperty(Button)
    timer_stop = ObjectProperty(Button)
    tot_sec = 0    

    def __init__(self, **kwargs): # Widgets without .kv file
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 4
        self.current_time = '00:00'        

    def update_time(self, instance):    
        timer = Clock.schedule_interval(self.timer, 1.0 / 1.0)
        instance.disabled = True
        # self.stop_button.disabled = False
        self.timer_stop.disabled = False

    def stop_updating(self, instance):
        Clock.unschedule(self.timer)
        instance.disabled = True
        # self.timer_button.disabled = False
        self.timer_start.disabled = False

    def timer(self, instance):
        # Code
        

class ClockApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        # Landing screen
        self.landing_screen = LandingScreen()
        screen = Screen(name='Landing')
        screen.add_widget(self.landing_screen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        # Timer screen
        self.timer_screen = TimerScreen()
        screen = Screen(name='Timer')
        screen.add_widget(self.timer_screen)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager

    def go_to_landing(self):
        clock_app.screen_manager.current = 'Landing'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    clock_app = ClockApp()
    clock_app.run()
```

**kv file**

```
<TimerScreen>:
    rows: 5
    Label:
        font_size: 60       
        text: root.current_time
    
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        Label:
            text: ''
        Button:
            id: 'timer_start'
            text: 'Start'
            on_press: root.update_time(self)
        Label:
            text: ''
        Label:
            text: ''
        Button:
            id: 'timer_stop'
            text: 'Stop'
            on_press: root.stop_updating(self)
            disabled: True
        Label:
            text: ''
        Label:
            text: ''
        Label:
            text: ''
        Label:
            text: ''
        
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'                
            Button:
                text: 'Back'
                width: root.width / 7
                size_hint_x: None
                on_press: app.go_to_landing()


<LandingScreen>:
    rows: 7
    Label:
        font_size: 50
        text: 'Clock types'
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1

    GridLayout:
        cols:3
        Label:
            text: ''
        Button:
            text: 'Timer'
            on_press: root.go_to_timer()
        Label:
            text: ''
        Label:
            text: ''
        Button:
            text: 'Countdown'
            on_press: root.go_to_countdown()
        Label:
            text: ''
        Label:
            text: ''
    
    Label:
        text: ''
```

Comment: Try adding `self` to the call in `kv`. Like `root.update_time(self)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment John. It partially works. Now I can click on my button once, but when done the other button doesn't get enabled. I guess I should modify the 'self.timer_button.disabled = False' part in my functions to reference the buttons created in the kv file. Any idea how?

Comment: You can add an `id` to both of those `Buttons` in the `kv` file, then use that to access the other `Button`. Cannot say more without seeing more code.

Comment: I have edited my question to include almost all of my code (I deleted code not relevant to make it less hefty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is mostly working. Just a few notes on the use of the `ids`:

1. You should not use a string literal as an `id`. Instead of `id: 'timer_start'`, use `id: timer_start`. If you use a string literal, you will encounter problems if you try to reference it elsewhere in the `kv` (it will be interpreted as a string, not an `id`).
2. When declaring an `ObjectProperty` in a class that will be defined by an `id` in the `kv`, use `ObjectProperty(None)` in the declaration in the class.
3. Use declarations in the `kv` to match up with the declarations in the class.

Applying the above to your python code:

```
class TimerScreen(GridLayout):
    current_time = StringProperty()
    timer_start = ObjectProperty(None)
    timer_stop = ObjectProperty(None)
    tot_sec = 0
```

and in the corresponding `kv`:

```
<TimerScreen>:
    timer_start: timer_start
    timer_stop: timer_stop
    rows: 5
```

and the `ids` should be changed to:

```
    Button:
        id: timer_start
        text: 'Start'
        on_press: root.update_time(self)
```

and:

```
    Button:
        id: timer_stop
        text: 'Stop'
        on_press: root.stop_updating(self)
        disabled: True
```

The typical declaration of an `ObjectProperty` in `kv` like:

```
timer_start: timer_start
```

can be confusing, but that is how it is usually done. I prefer to use a different name for the `ObjectProperty`, to make it clearer. The first name in the above is the name of the `ObjectProperty`, and the second is the `id`. They just happen to have the same name.

Comment: Hey John, I made the mentioned changes and now it's working. Thanks a lot for your solution and explanation. It really helped me understand a bit more what was going on!! You rock!